# Rails: HABTM Relationship. Retrieve the object that has two references

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :chats
end
```

and

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Which is a many_to_many relationship and what I want is to recover the only possible chat that exists with 2 users

eg.

```
me = current_user
user_to_chat = User.find(any_user_except_me)

chat = Chat.new

me.chats.each do |current_chat|
  if current_chat.users.include?(user_to_chat)
    chat = current_chat
    break
  end
end
```

What is the better way to do this query?

thx!

Comment: If you can, you should consider changing these to `:has_many :through` relationships.  Unless you are on an old version of Rails, this is a better construct.

Comment: I'll find out more about. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#find` which will return the first item in the collection for which the block is not `false`.

```
chat = me.chats.find { |c| c.users.include?(user_to_chat) }
```

You could also use intersections:

```
chat = (me.chats & user_to_chat.chats).first
```